# How to pick a specific object from a Linq Query using Distinct?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with two or more objects of class Agent.

Name = "A"

Priority = 0

ResultCount = 100

;

Name = "B"

Priority = 1

ResultCount = 100

;

Both objects have the same ResultCount. In that case I only need one object and not two or more. I did this with a Linq Query with Distinct and an custom made Comparer.

```
IEnumerable<Agent> distinctResultsAgents = 
(from agt in distinctUrlsAgents select agt).Distinct(comparerResultsCount);
```

With this query I get only one object from the list but I never know which one.
But I don't want just any object, I want object "B" because the Priority is higher then object "A".
How can I do that?

My custom Comparer is very simple and has a method like this:

```
    public bool Equals(Agent x, Agent y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        if (x.ResultCount == y.ResultCount)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I always chuckle at questions of the form: "How do I do X using Y" when you should be asking "How do I do X."  It would be like asking, "How do I iron my shirt using a baseball bat?"

Comment: @tster: On the other hand, it shows that the OP has put some thought in the problem and doesn't just ask to "send teh codez plz". :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First group the elements by `ResultCount` so that you only get one result for each distinct value of `ResultCount`. Then for each group select the element in that group with the highest priority.

Try this query:

```
IEnumerable<Agent> distinctResultsAgents =
    from d in distinctUrlsAgents
    group d by d.ResultCount into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Priority).First();
```

If you use [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) there is a function called [MaxBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/tags/1.0-beta/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) that you could use instead of the last line, but note that it only works for LINQ To Objects.

Comment: FirstOrDefault -- if the collection is empty

Comment: @tvanfosson: I don't think it is necessary to use FirstOrDefault here. If the collection is empty there will be no groups so First will not be called.

Comment: ah, yes, Select is operating on the enumeration of `IGrouping<TKey,TSource>` and the orderby/first is applied to each of these in the collection, not to the enumeration itself.  Sorry for the mistake.